# Security of wireless mice from Microsoft

Tags: security, mouse, wireless-mouse

While looking for a wireless mouse I am surprised how hard it is to find security information on them (I guess most consumers simply don't care). I managed to find some information about [security in Logitech devices](http://www.logitech.com/images/pdf/roem/Advanced_24_Unifying_FINAL070709.pdf). Is there any similar information about Microsoft mice I failed to find?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I could not find a general document like the one you posted, but this Google search shows that some models use 128-bit AES encryption. I would use the following search, and add your specific model to the search.

Search "microsoft wireless mouse or keyboard encryption site:microsoft.com" (without the quotes).

http://www.google.com/#sclient=psy&hl=en&source=hp&q=microsoft%20wireless%20mouse%20or%20keyboard%20encryption%20site%3Amicrosoft.com&aq=&aqi=&aql=&oq=&pbx=1&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.&fp=ebf9b5871ec185b1&biw=1385&bih=895&pf=p&pdl=3000

Comment: Thanks. My various tries simply dropped "encryption". Now I find at least for some models...

Comment: It's only one click (and 2 free points for me ;) ). I didn't accepted answer in one case when neither of the options worked.